# Non-rectifiable bounded closed set

Tags: integration, general-topology

Find a bounded *closed* set in $\mathbb{R}$ that is not rectifiable.

When I say "$S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is rectifiable" I mean that the constant function $1$ is Riemann-integrable over $S$ 
(then one shows that $S$ is rectifiable if and only if $S$ is bounded and $\operatorname{Bd} S$ has measure zero).

I've heard about the Smith-Volterra-Cantor set but I cannot relate it to non-rectifiable closed sets.